# How to integrate i18n doctrine translation into zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, internationalization, doctrine-orm

Say I have an simple entity UserType. I would like usertype to be available in various languages because it will appear in drop-downs in the UI. How should I set i18n up to work in my project? It was not clear in the docs.

```
<?php

namespace Entities;

/**
 * @Entity (repositoryClass="Repositories\UserType") 
 * @Table(name="usertypes") 
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class UserType {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string", length=30,unique=TRUE) */
    private $usertype;

    /** @Column(type="boolean") */
    private $active;


    public function __construct() {

        $this->active = true;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $id
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $usertype
     */
    public function getUserType() {
        return $this->usertype;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $active
     */
    public function getActive() {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $usertype
     */
    public function setUsertype($usertype) {
        $this->usertype = $usertype;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $active
     */
    public function setActive($active) {
        $this->active = $active;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply add "@gedmo:Translatable" in your comment block for translable fields

```
<?php

namespace Entities;

/**
 * @Entity (repositoryClass="Repositories\UserType") 
 * @Table(name="usertypes") 
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class UserType {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @gedmo:Translatable
     * @Column(type="string", length=30,unique=TRUE)
     */
    private $usertype;

    /** @Column(type="boolean") */
    private $active;

    /**
     * @gedmo:Locale
     */
    private $locale;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->active = true;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $id
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $usertype
     */
    public function getUserType() {
        return $this->usertype;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $active
     */
    public function getActive() {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $usertype
     */
    public function setUsertype($usertype) {
        $this->usertype = $usertype;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $active
     */
    public function setActive($active) {
        $this->active = $active;
    }

    public function setTranslatableLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }

}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this requires setting up DoctrineExtensions in my ZF project, and this is part of what I am stuck on. Have you managed to implement this already?